# Is there any syntax checker for Javascript (not IntelliSense)?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm working on one big JS file containing functions. Some functions are very long and sometimes I make mistakes about using a variable that is not defined in the code. Is there any checker that tells me something like "this var is not defined in this scope"?

Comment: Using a linter, such as ESLint or other?

Comment: Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more is off-topic.

Comment: @MiguelGamboa I'll check those.Currently, I'm using VS Code, but that doesn't underline variables that are not defined.

Comment: VsCode works well with ESLint. That's my experience...

Comment: I'll try that and see if I can get it work

Answer (score 1):

ESLint.
Most of the modern IDEs support it as well, so you may see the errors and warnings right in the IDE.

Comment: I'll check that one.